# How to extract nested object property using array destructuring?

Tags: javascript

I get undefined using this code:

```js
const json = {"records":[{"recordid":"1694119","recordindex":1,"status":"updated successfully"}],"message":{"returncode":1}};

const { records: {status} } = json;             
console.log(status);
```

How to get the expected: "updated successfully"?

Comment: `records` is an array, not a plain object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `records` is an array, you need to add brackets:

```js
const json = {"records":[{"recordid":"1694119","recordindex":1,"status":"updated successfully"}],"message":{"returncode":1}};

const { records: [{status}] } = json;             
console.log(status);
```